# Is there a ingest-attachment plugin for Elasticsearch-6.4.2?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins

Recently i'm using Elasticsearch-6.4.2 and i want to add the Ingest-Attachment plugin into the my Elasticsearch,so that I've went to the official website and download the plugin,however,i only found the plugin for Elasticsearch-6.4.3 and cannot support my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the following command and the right version will be installed:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

Otherwise, you can also download it from here: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/ingest-attachment/ingest-attachment-6.4.2.zip

And then simply install it like this with the offline file:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///path/to/ingest-attachment-6.4.2.zip
```