# How to delete documents from elasticsearch 2.3.5?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete few documents by single query in elasticsearch. I am using elastic 2.3.5 version. 
I am aware of a `'delete-by-query'` plugin, but it works only till 2.3.4 ver of elasticsearch (please correct me if I am wrong here). I tried to install plugin on my environment but it got failed.

```
C:\elastic search\elasticsearch-2.3.5\bin>plugin install delete-by-query --verbo
se
-> Installing delete-by-query...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugi
n/delete-by-query/2.3.5/delete-by-query-2.3.5.zip ...
Failed: SSLException[Received fatal alert: protocol_version]
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get
 detailed information
```

Following is my data available in `'jobs_index'` -

```
{
        "_index": "jobs_index",
        "_type": "jobs_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "source_job_id": "1888027",
          "specialty": "ICU",
          "profession": "RN",
          "created_date": "2019-10-10T08:30:00.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jobs_index",
        "_type": "jobs_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "source_job_id": "1888030",
          "specialty": "ICU2",
          "profession": "RN",
          "created_date": "2019-10-11T07:30:00.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jobs_index",
        "_type": "jobs_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "source_job_id": "1888030",
          "specialty": "ICU2",
          "profession": "RN",
          "created_date": "2019-10-11T07:30:00.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "jobs_index",
        "_type": "jobs_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "source_job_id": "1888029",
          "specialty": "ICU2",
          "profession": "RN",
          "created_date": "2019-10-10T07:30:00.000Z"
        }
      }
```

I want to delete the records which are having `'created_date'` less than "2019-10-11".
GET request for the same would look something like -

```
GET /jobs_index/jobs_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "created_date": {
        "lte": "now-1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please provide some suggestions on this ?

Comment: If you try to download https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/delete-by-query/2.3.5/delete-by-query-2.3.5.zip you'll definitely get something. Seems more related to an SSL problem contacting that URL.

Comment: Thanks @Val .I am on remote server though. can i put jar directly on elasticsearch..? is there is any other configuration required for this..?

Comment: You can definitely download that file and install the plugin from the ZIP file directly. See how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53333101/4604579

Comment: Thanks @Val, Issue is solved. Even one can put folder available in the zip directly into plugins.